# C# must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#

Hey I am trying to create a constructor so I can display the name and balance of a test account, but i'm not sure what to do. any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am new to programmin, and haven't been doing it for long.

```
public class Account
{

    public Account (string Name, decimal balance);

    public string name;

    private decimal balance;


    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    static decimal MaxPayInAmount = 10000;

    public bool PayInFunds(decimal amount)
    {

        if (amount < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (amount > MaxPayInAmount)
        {
            return false;
        }

        balance = balance + amount;

        return true;
    }


    public bool SetName(string inname)
    {
        if (inname == "")
            return false;

        name = inname;
        return true;
    }

    public Account(string inName)
    {
        name = inName;
    }


    public decimal GetBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question? What problem are you experiencing? Is there a stacktrace you could provide?

Answer (score 5):

Your constructor does not have a method body.
Use this instead:

```
public Account (string name, decimal balance)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

Also you should follow some naming conventions (e.g. you made one parameter with capital letter and one in lowercase)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)